Can't see my public IP in traceroute
From this traceroute:
% traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.250.201.78), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  5.003 ms  3.689 ms  3.323 ms
 2  100.64.128.1 (100.64.128.1)  7.707 ms  7.667 ms  7.956 ms
 3  172.31.27.1 (172.31.27.1)  7.626 ms  7.824 ms  11.714 ms
 4  172.31.26.12 (172.31.26.12)  8.736 ms  8.315 ms  8.342 ms
 5  172.31.26.25 (172.31.26.25)  8.061 ms  12.453 ms  8.045 ms
 6  google.baja.espanix.net (193.149.1.94)  16.864 ms  16.588 ms  16.416 ms
 7  142.251.53.181 (142.251.53.181)  18.164 ms
    192.178.110.153 (192.178.110.153)  18.587 ms  17.941 ms
 8  74.125.37.87 (74.125.37.87)  16.546 ms  16.761 ms  15.827 ms
 9  mad07s25-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.201.78)  15.171 ms  16.899 ms  20.844 ms

The traceroute shows a series of hops through private IP addresses:

192.168.1.1 - My home router
100.64.128.1 - An IP address in the CGNAT range (100.64.0.0/10).
172.31.27.1, 172.31.26.12, and 172.31.26.25 - Private IP addresses (172.16.0.0/12 range).

The first public IP address in the traceroute is 193.149.1.94.
So I assume my public IP is 193.149.1.94 (185.165.254.47).
However, if I use dig, it returns a different IP:
% dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
185.165.254.47

What's happening?
Regards

Traceroute does not show outbound interfaces like your public address. Traceroute will only show an interface where the expired packet enters a device.

You will not see it, and the reason for this you have to think about multihomed systems.
If a traceroute packet comes into your router & the ttl expires, all its kernel knows about is which interface it came in on.
If you have a multihomed system, and all routers do, to find out which interface it should go out of, requires it to be checked against the routing table.
So why bother to check which interface it should go out on when the ttl has expired? Just send the reply back with the address of the interface it came in on.
Even if you only have a default route, it does not matter, why bother bother with it and do the extra pointless processing.
